# Leanback - How to create Mosaic View?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

Since there are not many customized view tutorials online, I am asking this question here. I want to create a mosaic view just like [apple photo stream](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52cf190ce4b05933e864f776/t/5304d14be4b020fe6f12f0c5/1392824651668/streamappletv.jpg). I looked at the samples provided by leanback the RowFragment/Vertical row fragment are tightly designed to show one item in one row and one column. My goal is to be able provide a span size to some items to more than one row and column (same as that of the link added above). I wanted to know if someone has done such work and can provide some sample code to learn from. If not, I want some starter points from where I can start and build such layout.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to improve this question? There's not much I could find any work related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) to implement the grid and integrate a new Fragment with the [PageListRowFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java)